# How to apply multiple modifiers as one shape key?

Tags: modifiers, shape-keys, shrinkwrap

I'd like to know if there is a direct, or at least more efficient way (see 2. below) to go from "mesh with multiple modifiers" to "one shape key".

I was offered the solution to merge shape keys (from multiple modifiers) which I tried and it works. It's just too many steps in my opinion. My current solution works slightly better, but not much.

1. Detailed description:
   I have two meshes: human base mesh and clothing.
   My clothing mesh has two shrinkwrap modifiers.
   One regular which fits the clothing tightly to the selected shape key on my base mesh and one with "VertexWeightProximity" applied to bring back all the wrinkles the clothing has.
   Works perfectly, but saving "what I see" (all modifier results) into one shape key seems impossible to do in a fast and easy way.

When you apply a second/third... modifier as shape key it ignores what the first modifier(s) did, so you'd have to apply all of them. But I need a non destructive solution.
"Display in edit mode" and "Adjust edit cage" do not help.

2. My most efficient solution so far:
   Make copies of my clothing mesh for every shape key I want to have,
   Activate the desired shape key on my base mesh,
   apply all modifiers on the clothing mesh copy and apply the last one as shape key,
   transfer this shape key back to the original clothing mesh,
   delete the copy, repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 
Sorry, I understand you want to help keep it clean, but I don't want to merge shape keys. I want to create a shape key from "merged modifiers". I like the idea of "modifier groups" and the ability to "apply as shape key" from the whole group.

Comment: create the shapekeys from each modifier in order and then merge them into one key.

Comment: There is no such solution as creating shape keys from merged modifiers built in Blender, but you can do it with a Python script.